# Separate apdex threshold in Application Insights Analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, apdex

Using default Apdex workbook of Application Insights, I'm trying to separate apdex threshold by query name, because different queries have different satisfaction request duration.
I've added two parameters, each for particular query name.
I've extended analytics query by apdexThresholdByName column, which differs for each query name.
Then I've changed this line: extend UserExperience = case(AverageDuration <= apdexThresholdByName, 'Satisfied', AverageDuration <= 4 * apdexThreshhold, 'Tolerating', 'Frustrated') put there my apdexThresholdByName column name instead of static single parameter, which was before.

And this doesn't work.

Syntax Error: "Failed to resolve entity 'apdexThresholdByName'"

```
let apdexData = {Type}
| where timestamp {TimeRange}
| where name in ({Operations}) or '*' in ({Operations})
{OperationsFilter}
| extend success = columnifexists('success', true)
| extend Failure = iff('{Calculations}' == 'ConsiderFailures' and success == false, 1, 0)
| extend InterestingDimension = iff(isempty({SegmentBy})== true, 'Unknown', {SegmentBy})
| extend apdexThresholdByName = iff('POST Insurance/PostModel [actionName/elementid/widgetname/workspace]' == ["name"], {Insurance_PostModel_actionName_elementid_widgetname_workspace_threshold}, iff('POST Insurance/PostModel [actionName/elementid/widgetname/workspace]' == ["name"], {Insurance_PostModel_widgetname_workspace_threshold}, 0))
| where InterestingDimension in ({SegmentFilters}) or '*' in ({SegmentFilters})
| summarize AverageDuration = avg(duration), Failures = sum(Failure) by user_Id, InterestingDimension
| extend UserExperience = case(AverageDuration <= apdexThresholdByName, 'Satisfied', AverageDuration <= 4 * apdexThreshhold, 'Tolerating', 'Frustrated')
| extend UserExperience = case(Failures > 0, "Frustrated", UserExperience)
| summarize Satisfied = countif(UserExperience == 'Satisfied'), Tolerating = countif(UserExperience == 'Tolerating'), Frustrated = countif(UserExperience == 'Frustrated'), Total = count() by InterestingDimension
| project InterestingDimension, ["Satisfied Users"] = Satisfied, ["Tolerating Users"] = Tolerating, ["Frustrated Users"] = Frustrated, ["Apdex Score"] = round((Satisfied + (Tolerating / 2.0)) / Total, 2), Total
| extend Relevance = iff(["Apdex Score"] == 0, pow(Total, 1.6), Total / ["Apdex Score"])
| project-rename Users = Total
| order by {ShowSegmentsBy}
| project-away Users, Relevance;
apdexData
| extend ["Apdex Interpretation"] = case(["Apdex Score"] <= 0.5, '⛔ Unacceptable', ["Apdex Score"] <= 0.7, '⚠️ Poor', ["Apdex Score"] <= 0.85, '⚠️ Fair', ["Apdex Score"] <= 0.94, '✔️ Good', '✔️ Excellent')
| project Values = InterestingDimension, ["Apdex Score"], ["Apdex Interpretation"], ["Satisfied Users"], ["Tolerating Users"], ["Frustrated Users"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field apdexThresholdByName does not pass the summarize clause that follows it.

This summarize clause contains neither "name" or "apdexThresholdByName" in the by section:

```
| summarize AverageDuration = avg(duration), Failures = sum(Failure) by user_Id, InterestingDimension
```

so that segmentation does not propagate onward